# strcpy corrupts char array (string value)

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list, realloc, strcpy

The function below tries to order strings on a linked list in ascending order. When it returns the new list, it becomes corrupted.

```
void* order( void *ptr){
    struct wordlist *head;
    head = (struct wordlist *) ptr;

    struct wordlist *first = (struct wordlist*)malloc(sizeof(struct wordlist));
    struct wordlist *second = (struct wordlist*)malloc(sizeof(struct wordlist));
    struct wordlist *temp = (struct wordlist*)malloc(sizeof(struct wordlist));

    first = head;

    int j = 1;
    while( first != NULL){
        second = first->next;

        while( second != NULL){
            if( strcmp( first->word, second->word) > 0){
                if( temp->word == NULL){
                    temp->word = malloc( sizeof(first->word));
                }
                else{
                    if( realloc( temp->word, sizeof( first->word)) != NULL){
                        strcpy( temp->word, first->word);
                    }
                }

                if( realloc( first->word, sizeof(second->word)) != NULL){
                    strcpy( first->word, second->word);
                }

                if( realloc( second->word, sizeof(temp->word)) != NULL){
                    strcpy( second->word, temp->word);
                }

                free(temp);
            }
            second = second->next;
        }
        j++;
        first = first->next;
    }
}
```

For example, if input would be

```
piero
ronaldo
messi
```

then the output looks like

```
messi
ŽŽŽ
ronaldo
```

The above example is not tried on the code, but it will give you a clue. I believe there is something with the allocation of the memory but I could not manage to find it. By the way, sometimes the words come empty too.

Also, the wordlist is as follows:

```
struct wordlist{
    char *word;
    struct wordlist *next;
};
```

Comment: To order a linked list you shouldn't need to do all this memory allocation, you should be able to just change some `next` pointers around whenever you want to move something.  On a related note, you are allocating memory to `second`, then you are leaking this immediately with `second = first->next;`

Comment: You do realise that you can just swap pointers, right?  You don't have to `realloc` and `strcpy` to move them around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't copy the string into your temporary the first time around.

```
            if( temp->word == NULL){
                temp->word = malloc( sizeof(first->word));
                // You forgot to copy!!
            }
            else{
                if( realloc( temp->word, sizeof( first->word)) != NULL){
                    strcpy( temp->word, first->word);
                }
            }
```

See, if `temp->word` is `NULL`, which it *ought to be* the first time (note that you don't actually clear the `temp` struct so already you will get undefined behaviour), then you don't copy it.  The quick fix is to do a `strcpy` after you `malloc`.

Your `realloc` calls are all wrong.  You cannot use `sizeof` to get the size of a string.  Use `strlen` for that, and don't forget to add an extra byte for the string terminator.

Furthermore, you should not allocate `first` and `second`.  They are iterators for your data structure.  The first thing you do is discard their value so you leak memory.  Don't forget to `free` your `temp` structure as well as `temp->word` afterwards.

After you get that working, please stop all this `malloc` and `strcpy` business!!!

To move the strings around you only need to move the pointers.  No reallocation or copies required.  This will simplify your code down to a handful of lines.

Oh, and did you also forget to `return` a value from your function?

Comment: I just deleted everything inside the "if strcmp {}" part and did a pointer swap in three lines. It works like a charm. I wasted hours to fix this but it comes out so simple. Thank you.

Comment: No problem.  It was not wasted -- hopefully you learned a lot from the experience =)